# keep numbers of a vector that recurr more than 3 times

Tags: r, vector

I have vectors like this one: `c(1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7)`.
What I would like to do, is to keep only those elements that appear more than three times in this vector. In this case, I would like to obtain the following vector
`c(1, 1, 1, 1, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7)`
Is there a smart way to achieve this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: The vector is sorted ?

Comment: Yes, Othman, the vector is already sorted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of ways you can do this, one is the following:

```
a <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7)
a[a %in% unique(a)[table(a)>3]]
```

With `unique(a)[table(a)>3]` you select only those elements of the vector that have more than 3 occurrences.

The rest should be straightforward

Answer (score 2):

Try `rle`

```
rl <- rle(v1)
indx <- rl$lengths >3 
rep(rl$values[indx], rl$lengths[indx])
#[1] 1 1 1 1 7 7 7 7 7
```

Or

```
 v1[!inverse.rle(within.list(rle(v1), values[lengths>3] <- FALSE ))]
```

Or

```
v1[ave(v1, v1, FUN=length)>3]
#[1] 1 1 1 1 7 7 7 7 7
```

Or

```
library(data.table)
v1[setDT(list(v1))[,N:=.N>3,rleid(V1)]$N]
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
v <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7)
v <- table(v) >3
v <- names(v[v])
v
```